# Use XML data from an online URL as data source InDesign

Tags: xml, url, adobe-indesign

I'm looking to use XML in InDesign that comes from a live url as it's constantly updating from a database.

I know I can download the XML and import it from the desktop but does anyone know how to pull it straight from the XML page online at a URL?

Any advice appreciated! I'm running CS5.

Answer (score 0):

I wish! I've tried and this was impossible as of CS3, and I'm doubtful about CS5. Seems like it would be an easy feat for a plugin to accomplish.

I remember starting a discussion topic similar to this on Adobe forums long ago, because this would be great for variable data generated with a PHP script.

Comment: What pains me is in the back of my mind, I've done it successfully before! I remember the delay where it was summoned from the URL. I question my sanity now.